# How to convert string to float in javascript without parseFloat or casting?

Tags: javascript, casting, floating-point

For example given a string "43.44", is there any way to convert it to a float without casting or using parseFloat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an implicid type casting with an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus).

```js
var string = "43.44",
    number = +string;
    
console.log(number);
console.log(typeof number);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```js
let str = '43.44'

let val = (1 * str);
console.log(val);
console.log(typeof val)
```